# SPServices to create list items of a specific content type (i.e. specify the content type)

Tags: wss-3.0, spservices, asmx

I'm attempting to use SPServices to create items in a custom list that are of two different custom content types but I can't seem to get it right.

If I don't need to specify the content type of the item I want to add, it woks perfectly so I know my code is essentially good. I'm just not sure how to specify which content type SPServices should create.

Has anyone ever done this before?

Answer (score 2):

This was a typo on my part. I was not putting the `ContentType` field into the pairs array as an array itself.

The right way:

```
pairs.push(['ContentType', this.get('contentTypeIdName')]);
```

The wrong way (and how I was doing it):

```
pairs.push('ContentType', this.get('contentTypeIdName'));
```